# AngularJS кросс доменные запросы $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

Имею свой локальный сервер для разработки интерфейса, на node.js, api расположено на другом, тобишь необходимы кроссдоменные запросы. Нашел информацию, где советуют установить некоторые опции в провайдерах:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
```

Cделал.
На сервере с api Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.

Но запросы всё равно не проходят, 2 проблемы

1. Отправляет почему то OPTIONS запрос.
   попробовал в конфиге контроллера $.post({...}) - отправляется именно POST запрос...
2. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://somedomain.com/path/api/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: проще всего добавить на сервер так же разрешение для метода OPTIONS, потому что его сам браузер шлет при запросе на другой домен: [вот подобный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

Comment: @Grundy, если слать через jQuery - POST. Внимательнее читайте "попробовал в конфиге контроллера $.post({...}) - отправляется именно POST запрос.."

Comment: какая версия ангуляра используется?

Comment: @grundy AngularJS v1.4.7

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, OPTIONS запрос шлет именно браузер. Потому что, когда у меня была такая проблема, в Safari все работало нормально (он игнорировал CORS) и не посылал этот запрос.  Соответственно, я решил эту проблему, разрешив на сервере OPTIONS запросы.

Comment: @demas, извините, но я не понимаю "OPTIONS запрос шлет именно браузер". Повторюсь, что рядом с запросом через $http стоит запрос через $.post  и никакого OPTIONS там не шлется. Это "фича" ангулара получается? Что делать, если доступа к настройкам сервера нет?

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, не это я не понимаю, что значит: "что рядом с запросом через $http стоит запрос через $.post и никакого OPTIONS там не шлется".  Судя по вашему вопросу, оно как раз шлется. То есть, вы ожидаете, что его не должно быть, но по факту оно делается. Это так или я не так понял ?

Comment: @demas, я ожидаю POST запрос от $http.post(), так же как и от $.post().  $http.post() - отправляет OPTIONS, а $.post() - POST.

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, а $.post() не генерит prefligh OPTIONS запрос? В том же самом браузере и при работе с тем же сервером. Проверяли ?

Comment: @demas, я же написал, что в одном и том же контролере 2 запроса. 1й строчкой $.post(), 2й строчкой $http.post().

Comment: проверьте [этот вариант](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30296149/2881286)